# Meaning of "lit from behind through a cloud of metallic steam" and "strain a person’s sense ... "

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature, metaphors

> They stopped on a rising note. Dexter was standing in the bathroom
> doorway, holding Billy by the hand, **lit from behind through a cloud of
> metallic steam**.
>
> ‘Some things, Morty,’ he said, ‘**strain a person’s sense of humour**.’
> He swept through the room. The three of them sat foolishly, with fading
> smiles. It was dark, and the rain had stopped. Vicki stood up and switched
> on the lamp in the corner: the disorder of the room, its stuffiness and
> neglect, would have made her feel guilty had she not been already half
> drunk: as it was, she witnessed minor twinges of the appropriate emotions
> occurring distantly, as if to some other girl in a similar circumstance. She
> pushed her glass across the table to her sister, who filled it again without
> meeting her eye.

**Explain: Vicki and Elizabeth are sitting at the table in the kitchen and Dexter was in the bathroom washing his son and just now he is coming out of it.**

1. in the sentence "Dexter was standing in the bathroom
   doorway, holding Billy by the hand, **lit from behind through a cloud of
   metallic steam** Dose the verb "lit" refer to "Dexter" and the sentence in bold mean: Dexter appeared from behind them? and "metallic steam" is used metaphorically?
2. Does " somethings strain a person's sense of humour" mean: "somethings make us to tell funny things"?

Source: *The Children's Bach* by Helen Garner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the phrase in commas is a subordinate clause and can be removed from the main phrase without losing the meaning, so the answer to "who's lit?" is Dexter (as is answering "who's holding Billy?"). The meaning is that Dexter was lit from behind, so the light source is behind him (in the bathroom) and the metallic steam is a metaphor for how the steam from the bathroom looked like.
2. To [strain](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strain) means to put pressure on or to make it hard to sustain something. The meaning of the phrase is that some things are hard to find funny (after a while). There is some context missing to explain why did Dexter say that. Maybe Vicki and Elizabeth were repeating a behavior Dexter found annoying? You know, those things that can be found funny the first few times, but that stop being funny after a while - those are the things that strain a person's sense of humour.

Comment: Lots of thanks, So there is a light behind Dexter and The back of Dexter was lit. Am I right? And about the meaning of "some things strain a person's sense of humour" can we say it means: some things hardly seem funny? or can we say "some things make us not to be able to say funny things"?

Comment: Yes, the light is behind Dexter. And no, we can say "some things stop being funny after a while" - it's not related to saying funny things, but to finding things funny. If my sense of humor is strained by something, it means I'm not finding that funny anymore but I may have found it funny before, for a while.

Comment: I don't know why negative point! As a non-native their meanings were unclear to me...

Comment: I don't know either - they say you asked too many things in the same question.